# Vlookup Value From A Range of Values

Tags: sql, domo

I am trying to vlookup a value (rdate from table 1) within a range of rows (table 2), and return a "yes" if the value can be found within table 2 (with a specific set of criteria)

Table 1 - Sales by Date

```
rdate           strcompanynodename          Sum of MnyDollar Cost         
    --------------------------------------------------------------
7/15/2017         Chadwick Supply Co.                5100
8/1/2017          Northeastern Milling               5600
6/3/2017          Ford Paper                         25320
12/1/2017         Northeastern Milling               6600
1/11/2010         Chadwick Supply Co.                300
7/4/2017          Ford Paper                         2
```

Table 2 - Impacted Dates

```
rdate start         rdate end                 strcompanynodename  
    --------------------------------------------------------------
7/1/2017          7/31/2018                   Chadwick Supply Co.   
7/2/2017          8/2/2018                    Northeastern Milling 
2/1/2016          3/31/2016                   Chadwick Supply Co.   
7/3/2017          8/3/2018                    Ford Paper    
3/2/2012         8/2/2013                    Northeastern Milling
```

I want to sum the mnydollar cost by strcompany name from Table 1 when the strcompanynodename matches a value from table 2 AND the rdate from table 1 falls between the rdate start and rdate end from table 2 (when the company matches).

Updated with **EXPECTED OUTCOME**

```
strcompanynodename          match? (between dates)                sum of mnydollarcost
--------------------------------------------------------------
Chadwick Supply Co.            yes                             5100
Northeastern Milling           yes                             5600
Ford                           yes                             2
Chadwick Supply Co.            no                              300
Northeastern Milling           no                              6600
Ford                           no                              25320
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I see an issue there. "Northeastern Milling" has two rdates in Table 1. How are you trying to aggregate the Dollar value for two different dates. similarly for table 2. Please clarify ur logic more, and explain what all have you tried till now.

Comment: @RhythemAggarwal I want to sum all Northeastern milling sales from multiple dates in table 1 ONLY summing a given row when the date from table 1 matches a Northeastern Milling row from table 2 and falls within the start and end date.

Comment: @James: Could you show expected the result?

Comment: @James so for example, in ur case, the sales for Northeastern Milling   should be 5600 since only one of the rdates in table 1 is in the date ranges in table 2 ?

Comment: @RhythemAggarwal I have updated with expected results. Slightly changed original data.

Comment: @Tomato32 ^ see above

Comment: @James i think `Ford                           yes                             0` in expected result is incorrect

Comment: @RhythemAggarwal I think 0 is correct. but either way... not sure of solution

Comment: @James please help me understand. There is no entry for Ford with Dollar value 0 in Table 1. How did we get that value? i have a solution that works but i want to make sure i understand the problem correctly before submitting

Comment: @RhythemAggarwal you are correct, there is no entry for ford with dollar value 0... I am going to update the table accordingly.

Comment: Alrght. I'll post the solution and explanation

Comment: @RhythemAggarwal updated w/ a $2 entry instead of $0

Comment: I posted the solution with the previous data. The new data will work as well.!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    SELECT T1.strcompanynodename, T1.Mydollar, t1.rdate, t2.rdatestart, t2.rdateEnd,
case when t1.rdate between t2.rDateStart and t2.rdateEnd then 'Yes' 
Else 'No' end AS Flag
FROM SalesbyDate as T1
LEFT  JOIN ImpactedDates as T2 ON T1.strcompanynodename = T2.strcompanynodename 
AND T1.rDate BETWEEN T2.rDateStart AND T2.rDateEnd
Order by Flag desc
```

Comment: Would this not inflate the $ Value?

Comment: `8/1/2017          Northeastern Milling               5600`
this row will join with two rows in table 2 making total sales for northeaster 11200 for 8/1/2017 which logically seems incorrect.

Comment: @RhythemAggarwal: Oh no, my friend :))

Comment: @RhythemAggarwal this is an issue I have run into. Don't know how to sum just once per value in table 1.

Comment: @Tomato32 i could be mistaken. sorry. but, you joined the tables on strcompanynodename, then each row in table 1 for Northeastern Milling will be joined with 2 rows in table 2. Is my understand incorrect? I'll try this out on my pc quickly too

Comment: @RhythemAggarwal: My solution is not true. Need to clarify the expected result :))

Comment: @Tomato32 i ran ur logic. It was inflating the sales. See image here: [link] (https://imgur.com/a/34vCCos)
but a distinct and then aggregating outside that query resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the expected result using the below query

```
select distinct t1.strcompanynodename , t1.dollar, case when t1.rdate between t2.start and t2.end then "Yes" else "No" end as flag from
table1 as t1 left outer join table2 as t2
on t1.strcompanynodename = t2.strcompanynodename
order by flag
```

Explanation:
The case statement is used to create the Yes or no flag. 
The key here is to use LEFT OUTER JOIN (Read about joins on google). And to avoid duplicate records, i have added a distinct which would remove duplicates due to multiple entries in Table 2, since table 1 is the source

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Great! I will try this out. I am actually using Domo here so I am hoping the SQL to Domo conversion goes smoothly.

Comment: I am unsure what Domo is. I will do some research and see if i can make a Domo compatible solution quickly.

Comment: Domo is a BI tool that allows users to use a form of SQL to create custom measures.

Comment: https://knowledge.domo.com/Visualize/Adding_Cards_to_Domo/KPI_Cards/Transforming_Data_Using_Beast_Mode/01Adding_a_Beast_Mode_Calculation_to_Your_Chart

Comment: Thanks. i'll give it a look today.
Also, i see a logic flaw in the solution. In case of Chadwick, for 5100 Dollar sales, there are two Flags. Yes and No both corresponding to two different dates in Table 2. Ideally, i think based on ur explanation, this is how it should be since the dollar value is present for one set of impacted date range and not for other. You might want to select impacted date range to the case more clearly.